# when using this keyword inside method or constructor, does it matter the this keyword is on the left or the right of = sign

Tags: java, this

I'm new to Java and is trying to learn the concept of this keyword. My question is when using this keyword inside method or constructor, does it matter the this keyword is on the left or the right of = sign?

```
class Point {

    public int x = 0;
    public int y = 0;

    public Point(int x, int y) {
        x = this.x;//this on right hand side of =
        this.y = y;//this on left hand side of =
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, it matters.  `x = this.x` is not going to do anything in this context.  Did you try running the code and seeing what happens?

Comment: Its very easy to find it out by running your program and printing out the values.

Comment: If you didn't have parameter by the same name as the object variable (x) you could use the global x variable belonging to Point by referring to it as x, but since you do have a parameter called x, referring to x inside that method will refer to that parameter. So you use this.x to refer to the objects variable.

Comment: (A local variable *always* trumps a class member with the same name; `this` is used to explicitly indicate the class member.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does indeed matter.  In Java the variable on the left is **receiving** the value of the variable on the right.

So in your example:

```
class Point {

    public int x = 0; // line 1
    public int y = 0; // line 2

    public Point(int x, int y) { // line 3
        x = this.x; // line 4
        this.y = y; // line 5
    }
}
```

`x =this.x` is saying "take the value of x from line 1 and put that value into the x from line 3. so here your parameter x which was passed in (line 3) to create your object will now be set equal to 0 (because that's what created on line 1).  This is probably not what you want.

`this.y = y` is saying "take the value from the y parameter passed in (line 3) and put that value into the y created on line 2.  so your parameter y that was passed in will overwrite the 0 that you instantiated your y variable to on line 2.

One tip for remembering this that I learnt back in college was to **think of the `=` as an arrow** that always points to the left/receiver.

Therefore you have:

> x <--- this.x  (note the direction the arrow is going)
>
> this.y <--- y  (the left is always the the receiver of the value)

Finally, I would suggest that you don't get too caught up in the code and remember to **always think of the bigger picture**.

You are creating a class named Point.

*Why?*  Because you need an object to use.

*What do you need to create this object?*  X and Y coordinates.

*Would your class know these automatically?* No, therefore they are being passed in as constructor parameters.

*Now that you have them, how do you get the rest of the members (i.e other methods/variables) of your class to know they are there?* You have to assign their values to something that `this` class/object will know about.  And that is why you use the `this` keyword.

Hope this helps.  Stick with it.  You'll get better with time. ;-)

Comment: thank you so much for your answer! its more detailed than I had ever hoped for! Really appreciate it!

Answer (score 2):

Yes. `this.x` is different from `x` because `this.x` is the class's global `x` variable while just `x` references the one in the method/constructor, in this case it's the parameter.

This means you have to set the global variable `this.x` to `x`.

Comment: There is no such thing as a global variable in Java. Fields are specifically the persistent alternative to global variables.

Comment: @chrylis Ah, I meant class variable. Thanks.

Comment: @ChaiTeaNunes It's an *instance* variable, not a *class* variable (class variables are marked with the keyword `static`)